# Disjoint decomposition of a measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove if $E[a \lt f(x) \lt b]$ is measurable then $f(x)$ is measurable.  $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $E$ is a measurable set.  $E[f(x) \gt c]$ is the set of values $x \in E$ for which $f(x) \gt c$ or $\{x \in E:f(x) > c\}$.

A set E is measurable iff its complement is measurable.

Now $E[a \lt f(x) \lt b]^{c} = E[f(x) \le a] \cup E[f(x) \ge b]$.  This set is measurable. 
How can I conclude that $E[f(x) \le a]$ and $E[f(x) \ge b]$ are measurable.  My question is if $E$ is measurable and $E = E_{1} \cup E_{2}$ then $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are measurable where $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are disjoint.

Comment: What do you mean by $\:$ "$E[a< f(x)< b]$" ? $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Clarified in the question.

Comment: Should "implies" be replaced with "is"? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If $E(a,b)$ is measurable, then we can take the infinite union of them to form $$E(b)=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\le b, n\rightarrow -\infty} E(n,b)$$

Since countable union of measurable sets is measurable, this proved $E(b)=\{x:f(x)<b\}$ is measurable. The other direction is similar.